# Height-adjustable base for monitor

Tags: table-making, weight-capacity

I want to build a wooden base for a PC monitor which I can elevate or lower infinitely variable.

The height of the base/platform should be between 5cm and 10-12cm.

What kind of mechanism can I use? My first thought was something hydraulic but if there is another solution it wouldn't matter.

The monitor weights ~12kg. Space behind the monitor is ~10cm. The complete construct should simply stand on a table.

Comment: Have you considered a DIY scissor lift mechanism? There are many designs, some motorized, some hand-cranked, but all of them are customizable to your size and weight and travel requirements.

Comment: Good point. I will research for some tutorials. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Fabic, welcome to Woodworking. You want to be able to lift the monitor 5-7cm, between heights of 5cm and 12cm is that correct? Also need to clarify, do you need the mechanism to be able to raise the monitor itself, or just be adjustable for height? There are numerous possible options for something that can simply adjust for height, many fewer if you need it to have some motive power. One last question, what kind of space is available behind the monitor? If there isn't much it may limit possible solutions to things that can fit into a ~5cm vertical space.

Comment: @Graphus The monitor will stand on a wooden board which should rest on the feet. This board should be able to raise. Behind the monitor is ~10cm space. I would like to have a solution where I can move the board manually but a motor would also be fine if necessary.

Comment: Ah, well it should simply stand on a table.